# How to fix this cell in the GridView?

Tags: html, css

I have the following problem just in the Internet Explorer. The problem is: I am using the GridView control and one of its columns shows the Months as (Dec-2011, Jan-2012... etc). I want to show these months in one line (without any break). It works very well in Firefox as shown here:
**Jan-2012**

However, in the IE, I have it like this and I don't know why:

**Jan-**

**2012**

The css code for the TD (cell):

```
.grid .datatable .row TD
{
    font-size:11px;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:6px 4px;
}
```

**So how to fix that to be worked well in the IE as in the Firefox?**

(Sorry because I could not be able to provide you with the snapshots since I am a new user in this great community)

Comment: Consider setting the Width of the column to a little bit more than needed.

Comment: The problem is most likely in the width of the `td` element.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the following to your style to prevent wrapping:

```
white-space:nowrap;
```